# Display Century Gothic font on RDLC report in Azure

Tags: azure, fonts, report, azure-web-app-service, rdlc

I have an RDLC report which has a textbox that I've set to use Century Gothic font. The font displays fine when I run the report in my local machine. But when I deploy it to Azure (app services web), the font displays as Arial. If I use any other font (e.g, Comic Sans, Times New Roman) it shows those fonts correctly. I'm using Chrome browser but this issue also occurs on Firefox.

How do I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting inverted commas eg : "century gothic" in the font name

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that does not work. It just reverts to the default Arial font, even on local, because it does not recognize any font name in quotes. Is this something you tried before that worked?

Comment: How you are implementing the Fonts can u show me a snippet... and make sure the Arial font is not in the while body and if you are using  try to put !Important in front of the font.

Comment: It looks like this:

      `<Textbox Name="Textbox1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>Font</Value>
                <Style>
                  <FontFamily>Century Gothic</FontFamily>
                </Style>
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>`